# Replace a pattern that is within another pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I want to be able to replace a line break (actually remove) but only if they exist within quotes.

The string below should have the line breaks in bold removed as they are inside quotes:

eg - *This is the target string "and I **\r\n** want some" line "breaks **\r\n**" to be removed but not others \r\n. Can I do that?*

See image below for regex pattern. I can isolate the quotes that have line breaks in them.

Now I want to be able to find the pattern `\r\n` within these matches and replace them, while leaving `\r\n` outside of quotes alone.
[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text, we can't copy+paste that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable-width look-arounds in C#:

```
(?<="[^"]*)\\r\\n(?=[^"]*")
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%22%5B%5E%22%5D*)%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn(%3F%3D%5B%5E%22%5D*%22)&i=This%20is%20the%20target%20string%20%22and%20I%20%5Cr%5Cn%20want%20some%22%20line%20%22breaks%20%5Cr%5Cn%22%20to%20be%20removed%20but%20not%20others%20%5Cr%5Cn.%20Can%20I%20do%20that%3F) on RegexStorm.net (**regex101 does not support .NET regex**).

In case you want to remove actual whitespace, you can use

```
(?<="[^"]*)[\r\n]+(?=[^"]*")
```

Sample code:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=""[^""]*)[\r\n]+(?=[^""]*"")");
var removed = rx.Replace("This is the target string \"and I \r\n want some\" line \"breaks \r\n\" to be removed but not others \r\n. Can I do that?", string.Empty);
```

Output (only 1 linebreak remains):

```
This is the target string "and I  want some" line "breaks " to be removed but not others 
. Can I do that?
```